# What is the “RIOT” paragraph writing formula?

Tags: terminology, openings

In my high school, a teacher had an acronym which was a guideline for writing an entry paragraph to an essay. The acronym was “RIOT”. Does anyone know what these letters stand for and can they locate the origin of this pedagogical idea?

Comment: The only thing I can find is ["Review, Interview, Observation, and Test"](https://www.interventioncentral.org/sites/default/files/rti_riot_icel_data_collection.pdf) but that's used by school administration "when a student displays serious academic or behavioral deficits", not taught to students.

Comment: the OT stands for on-top, suggesting that the RI should be the opening statement, whatever it stood for.

Comment: Maybe it's like [BLUF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLUF_(communication)) "bottom line up front" -- I've also seen that as BLOT, so half-way there.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find a teaching acronym for RIOT.

The acronym may be **RACE** or **RACES**:

Restate the question
Answer the question
Cite the evidence
Explain the evidence
(Summarize)

Comment: I'm also seeing RACES: The same, but ending with "Summarize".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the origin of the acronym but I also heard this when I was writing essays in high school. If I remember correctly, RIOT stands for:

- **R**estate the source information
- **I**nterpret the information
- **O**ther opinions (explore and explain them)
- **T**hesis statement